# Audio player / Flash issue - displaying content header and characters?

Tags: flash, drupal, audio-streaming

Not sure how to describe this issue, but I only get it in Firefox and not any other browser.

When clicking around, the page sometimes blows up with the attached pic. Sometimes it has even more characters than that, and you can see things like LAME encoder referenced. Anyone know what the deal is? All site caching is disabled. I am no pro with flash so I don't know what is causing this.

I am using the Boutell XSPF player due to its support of Autoresume, if that helps. I added it to the list of players, and have the flash embed code in a block.

I am achieving this using the Drupal Audio module and submodules supporting it.

[image]

Comment: Weird. Do you get that output on a new page or within an active page?

Comment: If I start navigating the site, it starts to dump out. Latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a server issue. Doesn't happen live.